# Make virtual android keyboard take up space on page

Tags: javascript, html, css, progressive-web-apps

On my page, I've set the `body` to have a `height` of `100vh`. I want the virtual keyboard to **not** overlap the body when shown but instead make the body take up less space.

I was thinking that it might be due to the nature of mobile browsers but I would be glad if that was not the case.